# Unkown whitespace occurs above table (in asp.net datalist)

Tags: html, css, asp.net

There is an unkown whitespace above the table i created. When I inspect the code there are 
's and 's but I never used those. Could it be that it comes because I dont use tbody and thead? When I delete all the breaks and spans in the inspect it is correct.

[image: I think this is the problem but dont know where it comes from (I checked the master which I use for all other pages and dont see anything)]

[image: Under the breaks and spans]

[image: css]

[image: I zoomed out so you can see the table]

```
<div class="container" style="overflow:auto">
            <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">Product</th>
                <th scope="col">Voorraad</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Aantal</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-right">Prijs</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
            <asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:webshopConnectionString %>" providername="<%$ ConnectionStrings:webshopConnectionString.ProviderName %>" selectcommand="SELECT tblbestelling.Aantal, tblproducten.ProductID, tblproducten.ProductNaam, tblproducten.ProductAfbeelding, tblproducten.ProductPrijs, tblproducten.ProductVoorraad FROM tblbestelling INNER JOIN tblproducten ON tblbestelling.ProductID = tblproducten.ProductID"></asp:sqldatasource>
            <asp:Datalist runat="server" datakeyfield="ProductID" datasourceid="SqlDataSource1" repeatlayout="Flow">

        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ProductAfbeelding", "~/imgs/{0}") %>' style="height:50px; width:50px" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductNaam") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductVoorraad") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Aantal") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Text="Button"><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Datalist>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post an image of the problem?

Comment: Edited - I did .

Comment: did you check with 'Inspect' option on the table? Because maybe there is a style on this table that affect, and maybe it is not related to asp.net

Comment: And the container and table CSS code as well...

Comment: I added a picture!

Comment: You have a lot of spans and "br" if you comment that code do you still have the white space?

Comment: If i delete it in the inspect, it works but I can't find it anywere in my code. I never made those <br>'s and <span>'s and don't know why they are there.

Comment: The breaks and spans go away when i comment the code between the itemtemplate

Comment: Try moving the datasource outside of the container, and move the entire table inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is saw someone ask with a similar problem at the following page: https://forums.asp.net/t/1315224.aspx?extra+white+space+after+listview+ItemTemplate+ was if there was any extra spaces in the data anywhere. In the case at the link, I believe they just used text but it is worth a possible look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was weird but I just had to put the `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"` and it seemed to work.